# Retornar a Fragment sem precisar cria-lo novamente

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho um fragmento que mostra um Map, e no app tem uma tela de cadastro, o primeiro fragmento a ser criado é o do Mapa, se o usuário quiser se cadastrar vai iniciar outro Fragment, após ele se cadastrar quero retornar para o Fragmento do Mapa sem precisar instância-lo novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está trabalhando com *Fragments*, então você tem um gerenciador para eles, logo, você de fato só precisa instanciar uma vez estes *Fragments* e substituir no *container* conforme sua necessidade.

Na criação da sua `Activity`, você pode ter estes dois próximos blocos, com o gerenciador:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

E os dois *Fragments*:

```
CadastroFragment cadastro = new CadastroFragment();
MapaFragment mapa = new MapaFragment();
```

Então é só fazer a transação quando for necessário. Para cadastro, por exemplo:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, cadastro);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Certo, mas por exemplo eu só queria o CadastroFragment() quando realmente o cara clicasse para ir para tela de cadastro... Se eu tiver 10 fragmentos por ex, teria que criar todos eles antes na activity?

Comment: Creio que sim. Apesar de que em celulares o *garbage collector* deve ser mais ativo que no Java em si, então talvez você consiga ficar criando *fragments* sempre que precisar, pois a Dalvik deve limpar a memória mais frequentemente que a JVM.

Comment: Sim, pois não acredito que há outra forma de você manter o objeto sem ter o criado. Agora, pra ficar claro, `Fragment` é uma porção da interface na sua `Activity`, se você se refere à estes 10 *fragments* como "telas" de um aplicativo, talvez você precise rever esta implementação.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esse problema você pode resolver criando o fragment e adicionando ele e não coloque em nenhum container fazendo:

```
public static final String FRAG_A_TAG="fragmentA";
FragmentManager mFragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction mTransaction = mFragManager.beginTransaction();
//criar um fragment 
FragmentA fragA= new FragmentA();
//adicionar o fragment pelo tag
mTransaction.add(fragA,FRAG_A_TAG).commit();
```

Deste modo o fragment foi adicionado mas nao foi colocado em nenhum container, na hora de voltar a utilizar o fragment basta fazer:

```
FragA = mFragManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG);
```

E daqui voce pode colocar o fragment no container como normalmente faz.